Why did I have to restart my router to install programs
I have had a Windows 11 PC for 6 months. Recently, it wouldn't install any programs. It would run Chrome, but wouldn't run games that needed updates to play. Installing other programs like Firefox failed. The files downloaded, but installing them failed. I then wiped the PC and the remained.
I have a Windows 10 PC and had the same issue. At that point I thought it must be the router and restarted it, and everything is working again.
I use Windows Defender and turned off the firewall.
I don't understand what was happening and would like to know why I couldn't install programs and why the router restart fixed it.

This is not really a Server Fault question, it's more of a SuperUser question, but I will reply anyway: Memory fragmentation. I've seen this with a lot of consumer-grade hardware: after a while, the network card stops working, sometimes only for some specific packet types or sizes, because the control firmware can no longer find a buffer for the packet that's being received or sent. The memory is still present, but in the process of allocating and deallocating it, free space is broken into tiny little pieces in between larger in-use buffers, that can't be combined and so can't be reclaimed and reused. Forcing restart of the hardware is often the only way to clear out this unusable memory and return it to availability. This is particularly annoying in desktop computers because on modern PCs, net cards never lose power (so they can be available for Wake-On-LAN even when the machine is nominally turned off). So you actually have to cold start desktop hardware by unplugging it from the wall to let the 5v standby voltage bleed down, when you have this sort of network issue there.

I mean that certainly makes sense in terms of the PC, but I could download the installer but not install them on both PCs, I didn't try to install a program offline as at the time I wasn't aware this would fix it. This is why I am soo confused as why would being on a network stop me from installing. I tried turning off the PCs and no results but rebooting the router worked.

While it's unlikely that the problem would appear on both machines at the same time, it could happen... and then with both network cards stuck, only shutting down the router or fully depowering the PCs would clear them, But if I was to guess I'd say certificates: if the router was silently dropping packets intended for a certificate authority (CA), then when the system went to check if the CA was valid (to confirm whether it was safe to install) it would get no answer, and fail with a timeout, where if the network was not present it would simply not check.

That seems more likely, I was monitoring a issue I had with SSLs and certificate authority errors occurred, but im sure this wasn't always the case I think windows have made an update to make the PC not install programs if it believes the network is comprised. (Not my area of expertise)
